# Custom page Template and Script as a Plugin

Tags: page-template

I want to Build a custom Page Template. But as far as I know we should not at all touch Core PHP files.

let say our Custom Page template is custom.php, then where will this custom.php sit I mean in which folder in wordpress or it will go some where in the inner directories of theme?

Because Finally while creating a new page it should be available as drop down in WordPress admin.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the Codex, under [How to create a page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Creating_a_Page_Template).

In your theme you create a file called `my-bacon-template.php` and in that file you add the following to the top of the file, before any other code

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Bacon Page
*/
```

After that you can put any content you want and it will display on any page that you have selected to have this template.

Answer (score 0):

Amusing you know how to crate a page template. If not, refer to [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Creating_a_Page_Template).

Put the files anywhere in your plugin and this code should help you include them in Page template chooser.

```
function include_template() {
    return locate_template( array (
                'templateone.php',
                'templatetwo.php',
                'templatethree.php',
            )
        );
}
add_action('template_include', 'include_template');
```